# Can't get any definition working - Scheme *beginner*

Tags: scheme

I can't seem to get any definition working in my scheme code - I'm new to the language so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to define a cube function and I've got this written:

```
(define (cube (* x
                 (* x
                    (* x
                       )))))
```

Note: the problem I'm working on specifically disallows the use of the expt function, so that isn't a problem.

The error I get is

% plain-lambda: not an identifier in: (* x (* x (* x)))

And this remains true for anything I try and put in there. What seems to be going wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: Your interpreter expects the thing after the procedure name to be an identifier, like `x`, not a procedure application. Hence the message that `(* x (* x (* x)))` is not an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct syntax for declaring a procedure parameter. Also, you can pass several arguments to a multiplication at once. Try this:

```
(define (cube x)
  (* x x x))
```